# Sencha Touch DataView not showing items from Store

Tags: store, dataview, sencha-touch-2

I'm using Sencha touch 2. I have store that load from existing js object:

```
Ext.define('majestic.store.Dataset', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires : [
        'majestic.model.Dataset',
        'majestic.util.config.ConfigurationManager'
    ],
    config : {
        model   : 'majestic.model.Dataset',
        type: 'memory',
        reader: 'json',
        autoLoad : true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty : 'datasets'
            }
        }

    },
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.applyData(majestic.util.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfig());
    }

});
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('majestic.model.Dataset', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

    config : {
        fields : [
            'title'
        ],

        associations: [
              {type: 'hasMany', model: 'Layer', name: 'layers'}
        ]

    }
});
```

And view:

```
Ext.define('majestic.view.LayerList', {
    requires: ['majestic.store.Dataset'],
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    config:{
        store: 'Dataset',
        itemTpl: '<div>{id} is {title}</div>',
        itemSelector: "div"
    }
});
```

After looking at [Data view in Sencha touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535660/data-view-in-sencha-touch) i've added autoLoad and itemSelector, still no luck.

Though running

```
new majestic.store.Dataset().each(function(i) {console.log(i)});
```

outputs list of objects with filled data attributes.

**UPDATE**

I agree with @fbrandel that first option is how it should work, but after reading ST source i've figured out that store parameter of dataview is interpreted as:

- store object
- json store notation like in first example [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView)
- name of already created store which can be resolved using [StoreManager.lookup](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.StoreManager-method-lookup)

So I ended up with:

1. Leaving `store:'Dataset'` in View
2. Adding `storeId : "Dataset"` to store, so it can be resolved by StoreManager
3. Adding `stores: ['Dataset']` which caused creation of `majestic.store.Dataset` and registering it in StoreManager

**P.S.** It also could be done using `this.setStore(new majestic.store.Dataset())` in `initialization` method of GridView, but I prefer declarative way where posible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Try to set the store to 'majestic.store.Dataset' instead of just Dataset
2. Add the store dependency to your app.js like this:

   ```
   Ext.application({
       name: 'majestic',
       stores: ['Dataset'],

       launch: function() {   
          ...
       }
   });
   ```
3. Instead of passing a string to the store property, pass an instance:

   ```
   store: Ext.create('majestic.store.Dataset')
   ```

Option #1 seems to be the most obvious way how it *should* work. If it does not, this might be a bug in ST2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your missing an id field

Anyway, I'm building in Architect with no luck as well, but seems a totally different problem. I'll follow the tutorial in Architect (building your first mobile app) and maybe get insight.